# MFC dialog Border padding changed after switching from VS2010 to 2012 or later

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, mfc

After rebuilding an MFC app in VS2015, the border padding set by Windows changed from being added to the outside of the dialog frame to the inside of it. As a result of the change instead of a thick border making the dialog larger: the dialog size remains constant and the amount of space available for controls is reduced.

The default value of the border padding has changed between different versions of Windows.  It went from a smaller value (0?) to 4 pixels when Vista came out to make glass more noticeable and appears to have stayed there through 8.x, only to drop back to 0 for Win10.  (Caveat, I don't have any 8/10 machines available at work and am going off of Google here.)

This means that the amount of space for controls is varying between different Windows versions.  As a result it seems impossible to have dialogs that look good on all versions of the OS.  If I lay them for the 4px borders that are the default in V7/8 I'll end up with a noticeable amount of extra space on the bottom/right on a default W10 system.  If I optimize for W10, my bottom buttons will be cut off on W7/8.

This isn't happening in a clean test project, so it's something to do with specific code in my application.

I've attached a picture of what 0 vs 4 pixel borders look like in an app build in VS2010 or newer versions.  The image is captioned VS2015; but additional testing determined that the change was introduced with the V110 runtime (Visual Studio 2012).

The dialog sizing appears to be getting messed up in code that's using `MoveWindow()` to position the smaller dialogs around the main one.

I've extracted the code involved in doing one dialog below:

```
RECT             DlgRect;
double Fx, Fy, Fw, Fh;      // the dialog in the screenshots
double Px, Py, Pw, Ph;      // another dialog 
double ScreenHeight = (double)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

g_pRedactedDlg = new CRedactedDlg(NULL);
g_pRedactedDlg->GetClientRect(&DlgRect);
Fw = DlgRect.right + 10;    // 10
Fh = DlgRect.bottom + 20;   // 20

Py = 100; //size and position data for a different 
Ph = 50;  //dialog, calculated in code not shown

Fx = 0.0;
Fy = ((Py + Ph + 5.0 + Fh) > ScreenHeight) ? (ScreenHeight - Fh) : (Py + Ph + 5.0);

g_pRedactedDlg->MoveWindow((int)Fx, (int)Fy, (int)Fw, (int)Fh, TRUE);
```

Based on comments from @snowdude and @MichaelWalz I suspect the size being got from `GetClientRect()` and the size expected by `MoveWindow()` differ in how they handle the size of the dialog border; but haven't traced through it all yet to see what changes when I change the border size.

[image]

FYI The border padding setting is at: Control Panel - Personalization - Window Color - Advanced Appearance Settings - Border Padding.

Comment: Is it a standard dialog drawn in the ressource editor or is it a window/dialog constructed programatically ? Show some code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I think I've pulled everything relevant from the .RC file; this is happening with all of the dialogs in the app so the details of what the other controls are shouldn't matter.

Comment: Does it also happen with a newly created minimal MFC app ?

Comment: That shouldn't happen on a standard dialog based window, everything is in dialog units and will be translated to screen units based on factors such as font scaling. I imagine you have two windows here, an outer one and an inner Dialog one. You need to resize the outer one based on GetClientRect of the inner one.

Comment: @MichaelWalz An empty/default wizard created MFC dialog app doesn't have whatever the problem I'm running into with the app I'm working on.  If it'd be helpful in trying to figure out where something that's non-standard by current practice would be located at; the MFC version of this app dates back at least as far as Visual Studio 6.  Getting it to look and play with a current version of Visual Studio and look like a modern application has been a large part of my ongoing work on it.

Comment: @DanNeely you need to have a closer look at your code, there is certainly done something special with the dialogs such as resizing. Look at the OnInitDialog function. Try to add a new standard dialog for testing to your app and see if the odd behaviour you described occurs as well. If no, then compare with with one of the dialogs that exhibits this behaviour and you'll find out. Otherwise I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  Where present, OnInitDialog() on the various dialogs isn't doing anything other than setting default text values for controls.  Some dialogs aren't overriding the default at all, and they've got the same layout problems.  If there's monkey business going on, it's somewhere in the code for the main window/document/etc.

Comment: @DanNeely. very hard to find out without seeing the code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz if I had an idea where the code that was overriding default behavior was I'd gladly post it.  Whatever it is, it's app wide (confirmed by adding a new dialog via class wizard; it does the same thing); and the obviously application wide files (appname.cpp, appnamedoc.cpp, appnameview.cpp, mainfrm.cpp, appname.rc) total over 6k lines; so I can't just throw everything up as a wall of code.

Comment: @DanNeely OK; so there must be some override in your program that does things it shouldn't. You might look for calls to `SetWindowPos`, `MoveWindow`, `AdjustWindowRect` that are called during dialog creation. Good luck.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  Looks like `MoveWindow` is involved (see edit).  I'm looking and MSDN and stepping through the code now to confirm.

Comment: @DanNeely if you find out, please answer your own question here, I'd be interested what it was. I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of `GetWindowRect()` and `MoveWindow()` was changed between VS2010 and 2012.  In 2010, `GetWindowRect()` returns the dialog area without border padding, and `MoveWindowRect()` expects the dialog area with it; the size of the rendered dialog has the padding added. In 2012 the dialog area is returned with the padding added, and no padding is added to the rendered dialog size.

This was reported on [MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/768135/different-dialog-box-size-and-position-when-compiled-in-visual-c-2012-vs-2010-2008) and traced to a linker flag.  `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.01` gives the old behavior, `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,6,00` gives the new behavior.  VS2015s doesn't appear to allow specifying the version to be passed here.  Project Properties-Linker-All Options-Subsystem, is a drop down and only has a single option for Windows.

It's possible that the breaking change is the result of removing a [compatibility hack](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/6c1c67a9-5548-4e9b-989f-c7dbac0b1375/getwindowrect-on-nonresizable-windows-under-aero-glass) that was added when Vista was released.

For my application, I fixed this by using `GetWindowRect()` to compute the size of the dialog instead of `GetClientRect()` and then adding a hard coded padding value.

```
g_pRedactedDlg->GetWindowRect(&DlgRect);
Fw = DlgRect.right - DlgRect.left;
Fh = DlgRect.bottom - DlgRect.top;
```

This doesn't produce identical behavior to the old version, because the hard coded height offset is 12 pixels too small under Windows 7 and was truncating the bottom of dialogs as shown in the RC designer.  It's possible the offsets were correct under older versions of Windows; the MFC codebase dates back at least to Visual Studio 97/NT4.

Answer (score 2):

Setting in linker /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.01 I resolved the problem.

In Visual Studio 2015 is possible to set /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.01:

- Project Properties / Linker / System
- set SubSystem = Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)
- set Minimum required Version = 5.01

Answer (score 0):

In the linker options deaktivate System => SubSystem by selecting "not specified" or "inherit from parent or project defaults". In Commandline specify an additional option "/SubSystem:Windows,5.01"